# How to change my hover effect into OnClick event

Tags: hover

i’m (still) coding my first responsive site with skeleton framework
    (http://testi3.aada.fi /aada_web/index.html).

```
Now site uses HOVER on my content pages to show info behind image. I want change this into ONCLICK event so that user must click image to see content behind it.
```

How I do this?

```
// Mika
```

Comment: Show us your code for the hover function you have at the moment

Comment: /* -----
Hover 
------*/
.view {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #d3d3d3;
 cursor: default;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.view:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
 right: 100%;
 
}

Comment: .view img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.view h2 {
 font-family: 'Arvo', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 14px;

 background: #c23b44;
 margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 20px;
}

Comment: .view p {
    font-family: 'Arvo', sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-align: left;
 line-height: 18px;
}

.view a.info {
 font-family: 'Arvo', sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #1eb8ff;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #1eb8ff;
}

Comment: .view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #1eb8ff;
}

.view-portfolio img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: .view-portfolio .mask {
   background-color: #00afff;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.view-portfolio h2 {
   background: #00afff;
   color: #FFF;
}

Comment: .view-portfolio p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   color: #FFF;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.view-portfolio:hover .mask {
   right: 0;
}

.view-portfolio:hover img {
   margin-left: 100%;
}

.view-portfolio:hover p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}